# Comparable interface - how to compare int type?

Tags: java, comparable

I have two classes:

```
First implements Serializable {
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    int minute;
}

Second implements Serializable, Comparable<?> {
    First object;
    int temperature;
}
```

I had to write objects of Second class to binary file. I know they need to implements Serializable interface to do so and I have no problem with that. The problem is that I have to create a version of this code that will make it possible to add new object of Second class to collection chronogically by date saved in First class. So I need to compare Integers (month, day, hour, minute). I know that I have to declare method CompareTo in Second class. If I had to compare Strings it would be something like (if minute was String):

```
public int compareTO(Second object) {
    return minute.compareTo(object.object.minute); 
}
```

and it's done. But what should I do with those Integers?
And what should I write in a place of "?" in the code?

Comment: ? should be replaced with int because you are trying to compare ints

Comment: Your ? should be `Second` like this: `Second implements Serializable, Comparable<Second>`

Comment: you're right MagicMan. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the actual question here is about how you should handle the *multiple* int values. You can simply do a lexicographic comparison:

```
public static int compareByTime(Second s0, Second s1)
{
    First f0 = s0.object;
    First f1 = s1.object;
    if (f0.month > f1.month) return 1;
    if (f0.month < f1.month) return -1;
    if (f0.day > f1.day) return 1;
    if (f0.day < f1.day) return -1;
    if (f0.hour > f1.hour) return 1;
    if (f0.hour < f1.hour) return -1;
    if (f0.minute > f1.minute) return 1;
    if (f0.minute < f1.minute) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

In general, I'd recommend to **not** let a class implement `Comparable`. You should do this **only** if the class has a *natural ordering*. And for your `Second` class, this is certainly not the case. Using a `Comparator` is much more flexible in most cases. However, this method can be used either for implementing `Comparable` or for implementing a `Comparator`.

---

EDIT: Elaborating it a little in response to the comment:

This method is intended for the general comparison of two `Second` objects. You can either use it when you let your `Second` class implement the `Comparable` interface:

```
Second implements Serializable, Comparable<Second> 
{
    First object;
    int temperature;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Second other)
    {
        return compareByTime(this, other); // The method from above 
    }
}
```

Or you can use it when you create a `Comparator` for `Second` objects:

```
class SecondComparator implements Comparator<Second>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Second s0, Second s1)
    {
        return compareByTime(s0, s1); // The method from above 
    }
}
```

In both cases, you can insert new objects into a collection like a `TreeSet<Second>`, which is always sorted. Alternatively, if you used a `List<Second>`, you could, for example, do a binary search for the index of where to insert the object. (Or simply add the new object to the list, and sort the list afterwards, but this would be rather inefficient)

Comment: I see your point...but! I don't know if I understand this code correctly, but how could it handle a problem of multiple objects to compare? Now I can compare one object with another and say which is earlier...but if I already have 10 and I'm willing to add 11th? How can I say, where to put it?

Comment: @RIPI You can sort multiple objects in a collection using Collections.sort();

Comment: @RIPI You can add them to a sorted set like TreeSet.

Comment: yeah, and I assume that's the way I'll do it. I know how to build compareTo method, so I think problem is solved

Comment: @RIPI Added a short explaination. The question of how to manage multiple objects is somewhat unrelated to the original question, but has been responded to by Peter Lawrey (and I addressed it shortly in my EDIT)

Comment: off course. Sry for the mess and maybe too general main question. But you helped me so much. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Your class needs to be defined

```
class Second implements Serializable, Comparable<Second> {
      public int compareTo(Second other) {
```

In Java 7 you can use

```
return Integer.compare(minute, other.minute);
```

or for multiple fields you can do

```
int cmp = Integer.compare(month, other.month);
if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
cmp = Integer.compare(days, other.days);
if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
cmp = Integer.compare(hours, other.hours);
if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
return Integer.compare(minutes, other.minutes);
```

For earlier Java systems

```
return Double.compare(minute, other.minute);
```

Or

```
return minute > other.minute ? +1 : minute < other.minute ? -1 : 0;
```

In this case, if you know the range of your integers is less than 2 billion i.e. you can't get an overflow, you can use subtraction

```
return minute - other.minute; // if you know overflow is not possible.
```